# File/directory copy program runs on Xcode but gives segmentation fault 11 from command line using same compiler (clang)

Tags: c, c99, c11

EDIT 2: The issue seems to be rooted somehow in the total file size being copied. I took the source directory that I am copying and removed some files from it to reduce the storage space and now the program was able to print just 10 copies of it, which once again totaled around 150 mb where the 11th brought it to 165. Reducing or increasing the number of characters in the file name itself within reasonable bounds (2-25 characters) seemed to have no impact either way, so I'm guessing the issue doesn't have to do with the directory path buffers (and Xcode would probably get the same error in that case anyhow).

Could this have something to do with the hard cap on stack memory that a bash script can use? Because if Xcode programs don't have the same restriction it would make sense as to why it runs perfectly for over 6 gb of data, but only runs (perfectly) for around 150-160 mb through the command line.

If it has something to do with a limitation on the command line or on how much memory a bash script can use, my question then is how could I optimize it properly to avoid this kind of error?

---

I'm writing a program that takes user input for a given directory and creates a copy of it and its contents at another directory for a specific number of times from an argument. When I run it from Xcode using clang it compiles and runs perfectly, makes all the copies with no issues as far as I can see. When I try to run the exact same program, with clang, from the command line, it makes about 4-5 copies before giving "segmentation fault 11: (core dumped)".

---

EDIT: It runs just fine on Xcode for any number of copies (I have tried up to 150 totalling around 6gb), and when I run it from the command line it runs fine for 4 copies (around 160 mb total), at the 5th one it starts to mess up.

When I used lldb (backtrack) to debug I got the following:

```
    * thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x68)
    * frame #0: 0x00007fffc32ce6a0 libsystem_c.dylib`flockfile + 4
      frame #1: 0x00007fffc32d183c libsystem_c.dylib`fwrite + 72
      frame #2: 0x0000000100001550 copy`fcopy(s_dir="/temp/", s_name="mov1 copy 7.mov", d_dir="/Users/Ziad/Downloads/temp 5/", d_name="mov1 copy 7.mov") at main.c:69
      frame #3: 0x0000000100001818 copy`copy_contents(source_dir="/temp", dest_dir="/Users/Ziad/Downloads/temp 5") at main.c:100
      frame #4: 0x0000000100001abc copy`dir_copy(search_d="/", copy_d="temp", dest_d="/Users/Ziad/Downloads/", count=25) at main.c:133
      frame #5: 0x0000000100001bbf copy`distribute(search_d="/", copy_d="temp", username="Ziad", c_each=25) at main.c:153
      frame #6: 0x0000000100001db7 copy`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff5fbffa80) at main.c:179
      frame #7: 0x00007fffc325c235 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

---

Larger portion of code as requested:

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <math.h>
#include    <pthread.h>
#include    <sys/types.h>
#include    <sys/stat.h>
#include    <dirent.h>
#include    <errno.h>
#include    <pwd.h>
#include    <grp.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <unistd.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <fcntl.h>

enum {
    FOUND = 0,
    NFOUND = 1,
    RERROR = 3,
    OERROR = 4,
    DUPLIC = 5,
} ErrorCodes;

typedef struct dirent   dirent;
typedef DIR             dir;
typedef FILE            file;

int dir_copy(char* search_d, char* copy_d, char* dest_d, size_t count);

int dir_check(char* search_d, char* find_d) {
    dir*    dirp = opendir(search_d);
    dirent* dp;
    while (dirp) {
        if ((dp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(dp->d_name, find_d) == 0) {
                closedir(dirp);
                return FOUND;
            }
        }
        else {
            closedir(dirp);
            return NFOUND;
        }
    }
    return OERROR;
}

int dir_test(char* dir_t) {
    dir*    dirp = opendir(dir_t);
    if (dirp) {
        closedir(dirp);
        return FOUND;
    }
    else {
        return OERROR;
    }
}

int fcopy(char* s_dir, char* s_name, char* d_dir, char* d_name) {
    char    buf[BUFSIZ], sbuf[BUFSIZ], dbuf[BUFSIZ];
    size_t  n;
    sprintf(sbuf, "%s%s", s_dir, s_name);
    sprintf(dbuf, "%s%s", d_dir, d_name);
    file*   file_s = fopen(sbuf, "r");
    file*   file_d = fopen(dbuf, "w");

    while ((n = fread(buf, sizeof(char), sizeof(buf), file_s)) > 0) {
        if (fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), n, file_d) != n) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void    copy_contents(char* source_dir, char* dest_dir) {
    dir*    dirp_s = opendir(source_dir);
    dir*    dirp_d = opendir(dest_dir);
    dirent* dp_s;
    dirent* dp_d;
    char    sbuf[BUFSIZ], dbuf[BUFSIZ], cbuf[BUFSIZ];
    char    sdbuf[BUFSIZ], ddbuf[BUFSIZ];
    sprintf(sdbuf, "%s", source_dir);
    sprintf(ddbuf, "%s", dest_dir);
    while (dirp_s && dirp_d) {
        errno = 0;
        if ((dp_s = readdir(dirp_s)) != NULL) {
            sprintf(sbuf, "%s/", sdbuf);
            sprintf(dbuf, "%s/", ddbuf);
            sprintf(cbuf, "%s%s", sbuf, dp_s->d_name);
            if (dir_test(cbuf) == FOUND) {
                if (strcmp(dp_s->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dp_s->d_name, "..") == 0) {
                    ;
                }
                else {
                    dir_copy(sbuf, dp_s->d_name, dbuf, 1);
                }
            }
            else {
                fcopy(sbuf, dp_s->d_name, dbuf, dp_s->d_name);
            }
        }
        else {
            closedir(dirp_s);
            closedir(dirp_d);
            break;

        }
    }
}

int dir_copy(char* search_d, char* copy_d, char* dest_d, size_t count) {
    int     dcount;
    char    sbuf[BUFSIZ], cbuf[BUFSIZ], dbuf[BUFSIZ];
    char    sdbuf[BUFSIZ], cdbuf[BUFSIZ], ddbuf[BUFSIZ];
    sprintf(sdbuf, "%s", search_d);
    sprintf(cdbuf, "%s", copy_d);
    sprintf(ddbuf, "%s", dest_d);
    if (dir_check(sdbuf, cdbuf) == FOUND) {
        for (dcount = 0; dcount < count; dcount++) {
            sprintf(sbuf, "%s%s", sdbuf, cdbuf);
            if (dcount > 0) {
                sprintf(dbuf, "%s%s %d", ddbuf, cdbuf, dcount);
            }
            else {
                sprintf(dbuf, "%s%s", ddbuf, cdbuf);
            }
            sprintf(cbuf, "%s %d", cdbuf, dcount);
            if (dir_check(search_d, cbuf) == FOUND) {
                return DUPLIC;
            }
            mkdir(dbuf, ACCESSPERMS);
            copy_contents(sbuf, dbuf);
        }
        return FOUND;
    }
    return NFOUND;
}

char* read_in(char* str, int buflen, FILE* stream)
{
    if (fgets(str, buflen, stream) != 0)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(str);
        if (len > 0 && str[len - 1] == '\n')
            str[len - 1] = '\0';
        return str;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    dir_copy("/", "temp", "/Users/", 7);

    return 0;
}
```

`dir_copy()` takes the first argument for the directory to search in (`search_d`), the second argument for the directory to copy (`copy_d`), an argument for the destination directory (`dest_d`), which are passed in as strings. The last argument is `size_t count` which is the number of copies of `copy_d` that should be made in `dest_d`.

Comment: This is not the way to use `errno`.

Comment: You need to error check the `opendir()` calls.  What do `dir_test()` and `dir_check()` do?  How is this invoked — show a minimal `main()` with at least a call to the code with hardwired directory names (that causes a crash).  Describe or show the depth of the directory hierarchy you're copying.  You don't preserve permissions on copied files AFAICS.  You aren't reliably closing directory streams because you mis-test `errno`.

Comment: Also, see [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). When you get a segmentation fault, one of the first steps is to run the code in the debugger and find where the crash occurs — the bit of code triggers the crash? When you know that, you can work backwards to the cause. Even if you know nothing else about debuggers, knowing how to run the program and find the stack backtrace when it crashes are the two key items. Everything else is peripheral (very useful, but peripheral). Another key step is ensuring that you compile and link with `-g`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'll update the main post, but to answer your question: `dir_test()` checks whether or not a directory entry is another directory or if it's a file that can be copied, and `dir_check()` checks whether an entry is found inside a directory stream or not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I apologize if this question shouldn't have been posted but the only reason I felt it was worth asking was because of the difference in behaviors between Xcode and the command line which led me to become genuinely confused as to what is going on.

Comment: And we were completely unable to reproduce the problem because you've not provided an MCVE ([MCVE]), so it is very hard to see what's going wrong and what you're doing wrong.  It's not that the question shouldn't be asked — it's that it needs to be asked in a way that allows people to provide an answer.  That isn't easy, but it is necessary.  You have to reduce the problem to something that allows us to help you.  That's quite hard work; the reduction process often reveals the problem.  You are using a VCS (version control system) and can make edits to your code on a branch etc, can't you?

Comment: Now you've updated the question, I'll try to look at it later, but I have to at least pretend to do some work for a few hours.

Comment: Your code uses a type `dir`; the conventional name is `DIR`, I think.  Your code uses a type `dirent`; the conventional name is `struct dirent`.  Your code uses a type `file`; the conventional name is `FILE`.  Your code uses some names — probably enumerations or defines — such as `FOUND`, `NFOUND`, `OERROR`, `DUPLIC`; you don't show those.  You show the function `read_in()` but it is never called; we don't need that.  All of these issues make it harder than it should be to compile and test your code.

Comment: I don't yet follow the logic of the `dir_copy()` call in `main()` — and I'm loath to run it until I do; `dir_copy("/", "temp", "/Users", 7);` — is it looking for 7 directory entries in `/Users` and copying to … `/temp`?  Please explain what the magic numbers and names are for.

Comment: the posted code has MANY unused variables and function parameters.  The posted code is missing the needed include statements for the header files.  Do you expect us to guess as to which header files your 'real' code actually includes.   When compiling, enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successfull, call `perror()` to output the enclosed text and the text reason the system thinks the function failed to `stderr`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: the function: `fread()` can have a returned value of -1 or 0 or the number characters read.  The code needs to check for all three conditions

Comment: when calling the function: `opendif()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `errno = 0;`  in general, do not be setting `errno` in user program.s

Comment: regarding: `if (fgets(str, buflen, stream) != 0)`  This would be much better written as: `if ( fgets(str, buflen, stream) )`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) insert a (reasonable) space: inside parens, inside square braces, after commas,  after semicolons, around C operators